# KPI target thresholds in PerformancePoint 2010

Tags: mdx, performancepoint, kpi

I need help setting the threshold values in KPIs. In the screenshot below, the KPI has an Actual value and a Target value which is compared to the Actual value. The scoring pattern is set to 'Increasing is better' and the selected banding method is 'band by normalized value of Actual/Target'.

Is it possible to have threshold values for each band (green, red, and yellow) calculated dynamically based on an MDX formula, or do they have to be typed in as static values? In the sample below, the values typed in are 120, 100, 50 and 0%. Can we pull these threshold values from a data source?

[image: KPI]

Answer (score 1):

After extensive research, I find that it is not possible to set dynamic values for band thresholds. Values need to be entered manually for each KPI. I hope Microsoft introduces such a feature in the future versions.

Comment: Please add any links to the sources you found that describe this